# Excel VBA - If cells is part of merged cells pass the value?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some trouble to prepare macro which would help me to pass the value to another cell if the specified cell is a part of merged cells.
[image: Issue]

As you can see, cells A1-A15 are merged, in B1 I've written =A1 in B2 I did =A2, so what I want to achieve is that whenever I assign somewhere cell which is part of merged cells(A1-A15) the 'test' value is passed so there is no difference if I write =A1 or =A15 or =A10

I would appreciate any help of advice.

Comment: Some options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464265/how-to-keep-value-of-merged-cells-in-each-cell. Do the merged cells have to remain merged? Hideous things merged cells.

Answer (score 5):

You can detect if a Cell is part of a Merged Cell using `If Range("A1").MergeCells = True`.

Get the number of rows you have in your `MergedArea` using `Range("A" & i).MergeArea.Rows.Count`.

More explanation inside the code below.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckifMergedCell()

Dim MergeRows As Long, i As Long

i = 1
While i < 100 ' 100 is just for example , change it later according to your needs

    If Range("A" & i).MergeCells = True Then
        MergeRows = Range("A" & i).MergeArea.Rows.Count ' number of merged cells
    Else ' not merged >> single row
        MergeRows = 1
    End If

    Range("B" & i).Resize(MergeRows, 1).Value = Range("A" & i).Value

    i = i + MergeRows
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution. I haven't looked at MergeArea before.

Comment: @QHarr I have, unfortunately some managers use it in Excel since it looks nice to them, they are unaware of the numerous head-aches it gives us :)

Comment: @ShaiRado that's nice, but I want to have such option that if A1-A15 are merged so if in any other cell I'll write =A2 or =A15 or =A5 it will pass the value from merged cells ? Is that possible ?

Comment: @SebastianWdowiarz just run the Code above, why you want to use formulas ? you will get the same result

Answer (score 2):

In B1,

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A$1:A1))
```

Fill or copy down.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this formula, could you please explain how does this exactly work?

Comment: It simply looks for the last cell in column A containing any text up to the current row in column B.

Answer (score 0):

*what I want to achieve is that whenever I assign somewhere cell which is part of merged cells(A1-A15) the 'test' value is passed so there is no difference if I write =A1 or =A15 or =A10*

What you want to accomplish can't be done easily. You could do it with an VBA code that checks every single time you type something, **but it's not worth it.** The other answer you got here are worth it.

What you want to do is not possible because Excel works in a weird way. Let's say you have cells `A1:A15` merged. The value is ALWAYS in first cell of merged area (in this case in **A1**). So when you reference a cell inside the merged area, it will have a 0 value (a blank cell) always, unless it is the first one.

So my advice, would be:

> 1. Use 1 of the other answers, because both are really helpful
> 2. If you insist in using normal formulas, then instead of typing `=A1`, try with absolute references, try `=$A$1`. If you click and
>      drag, that formula will work for you to complete adjacent cells to
>      merged area.
> 3. I insist, use 1 of the other answers.